# Y-axis format type is not avilable in ApexChart

Tags: javascript

X-axis has a format type(Like numeric, datetime, category) attribute, but could not find Y-axis type attribute .

Is there a possible way to apply the Y-axis type - attribute ?

We have passed the following X & Y axis data to ApexChart :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgRNt.png)

**Apex Render :**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UEJ1.png)

**Expected Output:**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukXQc.png)

Could you please help us resolve this case?